# Error #1010 at falsh as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, volume

i am new to flash, i was created volume slider, and i was clearly created instance for all volume function but it give the follow error

```
 TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
```

the exact error place in the following code is

`bgslider.mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,StartDrag);`

my player code is

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

btnstop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,StopOut);
btnstopo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,StopOver);
function StopOver(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    btnstopo.visible=false;
    btnstop.visible=true;
}

function StopOut(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    btnstop.visible=false;
    btnstopo.visible=true;
}

btnplay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,PlayOut);
btnplayo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,PlayOver);

function PlayOver(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    btnplayo.visible=false;
    btnplay.visible=true;
}

function PlayOut(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    btnplay.visible=false;
    btnplayo.visible=true;
}

var soundfile:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://live32.radio.com:80/;stream1.mp3');
var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var sTransform:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();

 var isplay=1;
 var myMusic:Sound = new Sound();  
 myMusic.load(soundfile);
 channel=myMusic.play(); 

btnplay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,PlayRadio);
btnstop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,StopRadio);

function PlayRadio(evt:Event):void
{
    if(isplay==0)
    {
        isplay=1;       
        btnplay.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,PlayOut);
        btnplayo.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,PlayOver);
        btnstop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,StopOut);
        btnstopo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,StopOver);
        SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);
        btnstop.visible=true;
        btnplay.visible=false;
    }
}

function StopRadio(evt:Event):void
{
    if(isplay==1)
    {
        btnstop.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,StopOut);
        btnstopo.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,StopOver);
        btnplay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,PlayOut);
        btnplayo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,PlayOver);
        SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
        isplay=0;
        btnstop.visible=false;
        btnplay.visible=true;
    }
}

/*var bgslider = new MovieClip();
trace(bgslider.name);

for(var i:uint=0;i<bgslider.numChildren;i++){
trace(bgslider.getChildAt(i).name);
}*/
bgslider.mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,StartDrag);
bgslider.mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,StopDrag);
function StartDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    bgslider.mc.startDrag(true,new Rectangle(152,37,182,0));
}
function StopDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    bgslider.mc.stopDrag();
}
```

please give the correct answer anyone, thanks advance

Comment: What is `bgslider.mc` ?

Comment: bgslider is my volume slider background and mc is the volume control nab.

Comment: How did you define it ? Using mxml ? Then can you please show us some mxml code !

Comment: no i am not using mxml. just action script only

Answer (score 1):

That TypeError is usually an indication that you misspelled an object reference or didn't give it one at all.

Double check your bgslider and mc reference in the property inspector. Make sure it's not called bg_slider, bgSlider or something like that.

Comment: my instance name was correctly mention in action script, there is now spelling mistake

Comment: Okey, is the instance properly created then? I assume you're creating it in flash, is it added properly?